# Layout Code generation in Android

Tags: android

I have been an ecommerce App in android and facing a lot of problem in UI.I am unable to set the navbars , tabs etc  properly which is consuming a lot of my time.Is there any tool to generate code based on our layout like we have for web development?
Excuse me if this is a dumb ques, I am new to android

Comment: I think you need to explain your problem more.  If you have an xml layout you don't need code to set UI elements.  What is it you're looking for (or what are you doing, as you may be doing things you don't need)?

Answer (score 0):

If you use eclipse to develop you have a simple and basic WYSIWYG editor. If you open a xml layout file it will automatically open. It also supports displaying multiple languages at once. And allows for easy change in configuration, like resolution, phone orientation and themes. Using the tabs on the bottom you can switch between xml layout code and the WYSIWYG editor.

**But I do recommend practicing with building layouts just from xml, your layouts will most likely be of much better quality than dragging and dropping in any WYSIWYG editor. I use the WYSIWYG editor only for previewing layouts.**

Great tutorial for android layouts can be found on the official developers site: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

[image: Eclipse WYSIWYG editor]

Comment: The WYSISYG editor in Eclipse is a piece of shit.  You can't trust it, it gets any non-trivial layout wrong.